# Remote control a windows-ce device on the network

Tags: .net, windows-ce, remote-access

I need to setup an application on a Windows CE device that is connected to the local network, but I don't have physical access to the device.

I can only ask the user to perform simple steps on the device, but nothing complected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [Soti Pocket Controller](http://www.soti.net/PCPro/) to be easy to use as a remote control application (among other useful features for embedded development), it can be installed on the device using a cab file and the client application will show the IP address you need to connect to by clicking an icon on the taskbar/main-menu, so maybe it will fit your requirements. Note that I am not related to this product in any way, I am just a happy user.This is a commercial product by the way.
 If you need something free, maybe you could give [this wince vnc server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincevncsvr/?_test=b) a try.

In order to get any of these applications on the device you will need someone to follow some manual steps for you, I think there is no way around that. Maybe you can post the installation cab file in a web server with screen shots on how to install it (you just need someone to double click on it).

Comment: I have this VNC the problem is how I get it on the device without fiscal access to it.